# Outlook 2010 Calendar - cannot double-click on time to set new meeting

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar

Have you guys encountered this strange phenomena that outlook just stopped reacting to the "double-clicking" to open the a new meeting window on the calendar? 
(it won't even pop up the side window when "right-clicking")

Note: I can still set the meeting through the "new meeting" button in the ribbon...

OS: windows7

10X
 :-)